# CSS-Table despite intermediate elements

Tags: html, css

We can make any elements a table like this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjVwKX), using display:table and friends.

```css
.table {display: table; width: 100%}
.row {display: table-row}
.cell {display: table-cell}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Foo
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Bar
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Baz
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Bang
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

But if the HTML contains intermediate elements like this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyPwpQ), the CSS table styling no longer will work:

```css
.table {display: table; width: 100%}
.row {display: table-row}
.cell {display: table-cell}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="between-table-and-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="between-row-and-cells">
        <div class="cell">
          Foo
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          Bar
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="between-table-and-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="between-row-and-cells">
        <div class="cell">
          Baz
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          Bang
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Is thera any trick to still show a table, **only** changing CSS, not HTML?

Comment: May I ask why you would want to accomplish such a thing?

Comment: The easiest trick to create a table is to use a table. then you can nest each cell with whatever you want.

Comment: @Ibu You can nest, but not as part of the grid.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but not widely supported (currently only works on Firefox).

What you want is called [`display: contents`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-contents):

> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and
>   pseudo-elements still generate boxes as normal. For the purposes of
>   box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had
>   been replaced with its children and pseudo-elements in the document
>   tree.

```css
.between-table-and-row, .between-row-and-cells {
  display: contents;
}
```

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.between-table-and-row, .between-row-and-cells {
  display: contents;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="between-table-and-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="between-row-and-cells">
        <div class="cell">Foo</div>
        <div class="cell">Bar</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="between-table-and-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="between-row-and-cells">
        <div class="cell">Baz</div>
        <div class="cell">Bang</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, specifically to tables, there is a better alternative: you can display like a `tbody` element.

```css
.between-table-and-row {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

Note this won't solve the `.between-row-and-cells` problem.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.between-table-and-row {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="between-table-and-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Foo</div>
      <div class="cell">Bar</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="between-table-and-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Baz</div>
      <div class="cell">Bang</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If your columns have a fixed width, you can also consider

```css
.between-table-and-row {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.between-row-and-cells {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}
.between-table-and-row {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.between-row-and-cells {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="between-table-and-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="between-row-and-cells">
        <div class="cell">Foo</div>
        <div class="cell">Bar</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="between-table-and-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="between-row-and-cells">
        <div class="cell">Baz</div>
        <div class="cell">Bang</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```